# Power BI - Slider Slicer that Includes Time (Not just Date)

Tags: powerbi

I have a **Time** column that I would like to create a slider slicer for, similar to what's available for a **Date** column.

[image: Date Slider]

However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this. If I add a **Time** column to a slicer and set the visualization method to "Between", it shows a 1899-12-30 date without any other options. As an FYI, all of my data is within a 24-hour period so duplicate times on different dates are not an issue.

[image: Time Slider]

Similarly, if I do this with a **Date/time** column instead of just a Time column, it simply uses the date piece of the value and leaves off the time piece.

[image: Date/time Slider]

I know that one can add a "zoom slider" to some individual visuals to create a similar effect, but I need to actually slice the data based on time, not just adjust the visual display.

Is there a way to implement a slider slicer based on the time piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **June 2022**, creating a slider slicer like this for the time piece is not possible. This has been confirmed by a super user answer on an identical post of mine on [Power BI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Slider-Slicer-that-Includes-Time-Not-just-Date/m-p/2572000).

The filter pane can be used to accomplish filtering between two times, but there is no great way to do this in the slicer visual.

[image: Date/Time Filter]

**UPDATE:** A user in the corresponding [Power BI Community](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Slider-Slicer-that-Includes-Time-Not-just-Date/m-p/3370654/highlight/true#M1122295) post implemented a solution where they convert the time column to a number in Power Query and then format the number to look like a time. This way a slider slicer can be created based on this number column, but it will still look like a time value. An interesting solution that I haven’t tried, but that’s worth checking out.

Comment: Matt Kocak, thanks for your answer, I was having issues with the same topic and I used filter pane as you suggested. one thing that remains a problem is that the end user cannot access the filter pane, right? which makes is irrelevant for the usage in an interactive power BI dashboard

Comment: @ctrl_z hello! The filter pane can actually be made visible to end users. When editing the report, just open the filter pane and make sure that the eye symbol in the upper right hand corner is not crossed out. Similarly, you can show/hide the individual fields that you want to show to an end user.